# how to temporary store uploaded files using FLASK

Tags: session, flask, storage, flask-login

I'm creating a web application using flask that takes 3 input from the user: name, picture, grades.

I want to store these information temporary depending on the user's session.
and as a beginner I read that sessions are not for storing files, **what other secure way you recommend me to use?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to write the files to disk.

If this is really temporary, e.g. you have a two-step-sign-up-form, you could write the files to temporary files or into a temporary directory.

Please see the excellent documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Maybe this should not be this temporary? It sounds like a user picture is something more permanent.

Then I would recommend e.g. to create a directory for each user and store the files there.

This is done with standard Python io, e.g with the `open` function.

More info about reading and writing files also can be found in the official Python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files